# how to stop FLEX from caching?

Tags: html, apache-flex, caching, adobe

i'm working with a flex app I didnt design myself, in fact i really don't know much about the workings of flex. I want to disable all caching since its causing a lot of problems since we changed to a new payment method.

I know the disabling cache isnt ideal, but it just needs to be done for the moment.
I found a server side solution for this, but my implementation of it doesn't seem to work.

i tried setting it in the header, here's the piece of code for my index.html

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
...........
```

Maybe someone with experience on this matter is willing to help be out?

Comment: What is being cached that you're trying to prevent?  You mean the SWF is being cached by the browser?  Or are you talking about some data being cached inside the Flex app? Or do you mean something is being cached on the server?  Based on the code you provided, it sounds like you are trying to prevent the SWF from being cached by the web browser. Is that correct? You mentioned a server side solution, but your HTML code is a client side solution.

Comment: yeah i want to stop the swf from caching. very useful comment: im not stopping cache for the user/visitor of the site??

Comment: I'd recommend sending the right Cache-Control headers from the server. Which webserver are you using? Apache?

Comment: @Gerhard yes, im using tomcat

Answer (score 1):

A Flex application is in fact just a Flash file, which is a file with the `.swf` extension. Just like any other asset in a web page, you can make it reload simply by changing the filename. The best thing you can do, is to **include a build number** in that filename.

Suppose at the moment the file is called `MyApp.swf`, you could rename it to `MyApp-2.0.swf` and just change the build number whenever you publish a new version.
Another option would be to pass the build number as a URL paramter like so: `MyApp.swf?v=2.0`, but in my experience that's slightly less reliable.

Also don't forget that the server might cache the entire page. If that's the case, it would keep loading the old `MyApp.swf`, even if you changed the name. How to prevent this, depends on the server side language.

Comment: it helped, though chrome got the entire page cached, but i think ill be able to figure that out, thanks!!!